# How to find matching string with missing letter?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am having an array with string:

```
var dict =["johndoe","johnrte","jahnaoi"];
```

I want to make a function (with regex or other) to check if "str" with missing letter fit one of its item. Missing letter is represented by "#".
Let's say that the string with missing letter is "j#hn#oe".
I started that way, but I think I am not going to right way.

```
     function Checkword(str) {
      // Check were is the #
      var indices = [0]
      for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
          if (str[i] === "#") indices.push(i);
      }
      var regexel = "/^";

      for (var index = 0; index < indices.length; index++) {
          regexel.concat(str.substring(indices[index - 1], indices[index]));
          regexel.concat("[a-z]");

      }
      regexel.concat("$/");
      var reg = new Regex(regexel);

      for (r = 0; r < dict.length; i++) {
          if (reg.test(dict[r]) {
                  console.log(dict[r]);
          }

      }


  }
  Checkword("j#hn#oe");
```

In this case, it would return first and last item.

*** Edit after comment:

Which word should pass my test:

```
If str is j#hndo#=> dict[0], dict[2].
If str is j####### => dict[0], dict[1], dict[2];
IF str is Jonh#oe=> dict[0]
if str is a#ze#ts=> nothing.
```

Comment: Sounds like an interview question

Comment: Can you clarify what the question is?

Comment: so which letters are missing in the first and last item that the second one has? '#' makes no sense.

Comment: There can be several missing letters. Also it is not an interview question but a personal project ! :)

Comment: Starting or ending the regexp string with `/` is not going to work well. The `/` is used only for regexp literals.

Comment: You should show examples of which strings should 'pass' the Checkwords method and which strings should 'fail'.

Comment: I doubt if you need anything more complicated than `input.test(str.replace('#', '.*?')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment, this is the answer which is a lot more easier than expected. Thank you!

```
var dict =["johndoe","johnrte","jahnaoi"]; 

var dict =["johndoe","johnrte","jahnaoi"]; 

function ismissing(str){

    while(str.indexOf("#")>0){
        str=str.replace('#', '[a-z]{1}');
}

    var reg=new RegExp(str);
    console.log(reg);

    for(i=0;i<dict.length;i++){

        if(reg.test(dict[i]))
            {console.log(dict[i])};
}


}
ismissing("j#hn#o#");
```

output=>

```
/j[a-z]{1}hn[a-z]{1}o[a-z]{1}/
johndoe
jahnaoi
undefined
```

Comment: Based on my understanding of the question, I'd probably make it `str=str.replace('#', '[a-z]{1}');`

Comment: pretty much the same, isn't it?

Comment: No, with `.*?` you would match 'johndoe' as well as 'joooooohndddddoe', 'joasfdsdfhnasdfdsoe' and 'jhnoe'. Also `[a-z]` was the pattern OP used.

Comment: You are write! Thanks. I change it.